# How to use SSE in Nest.js

Tags: events, rxjs, observable, nestjs, server-sent-events

Can anyone help me please to understand and find correct way to use Server Sent Events in Nest.js?

i try to implement simple HTTP endpoint which creates a job queue, and when job is finished queue processor emits an event with job result, then SSE endpoint returns an observable pipe which listen an events from job queue.

Code is works but in console i get a message with memory leak in event stream when i adding a new jobs or reloading page, so i understand that my solution is wrong.

How can i correctly control connections and manage SSE endpoint?
Also how can correctly broadcast messages from multiple events to SSE channel?

Controller code:

```
@Controller('jobs')
export class EmailController {
    constructor(private readonly emailService: EmailService) {}

    @Post('add')
    async confirm(@Session() session: Record<string, any>, @Body() batch: BatchDto) {
        session.uuid = session.uuid ? session.uuid : uuidv4()
        const jobId = await this.emailService.sendMail(batch, session.uuid)
        if (!session.jobs) session.jobs = [+jobId]
        else session.jobs.push(+jobId)
        return { jobId }
    }

    @Sse('sse')
    async sse(@Query() query: UuidDto): Promise<Observable<MessageEvent>> {
        return await this.emailService.getResults(query.uuid)
    }
}
```

Service code:

```
@Injectable()
export class EmailService {
    constructor(@InjectQueue('email') private readonly emailQueue: Queue) {}

    async sendMail(batch: BatchDto, uuid: string) {
        const job = await this.emailQueue.add('send', { ...batch, uuid })
        return job.id
    }

    async getResults(uuid: string) {
        const obs$: Observable<any> = new Observable((observer) => {

        // Is it correct way to subscribe to events and broadcast them to SSE channel?

            this.emailQueue.on('active', (job, jobPromise) => {
                if (job.data.uuid === uuid) {
                    observer.next({
                        active: {
                            id: job.id,
                            data: job.data,
                        },
                    })
                }
            })

            this.emailQueue.on('progress', (job, progress) => {
                if (job.data.uuid === uuid) {
                    observer.next({
                        progress: {
                            id: job.id,
                            progress,
                        },
                    })
                }
            })

            this.emailQueue.on('completed', (job, result) => {
                if (job.data.uuid === uuid) {
                    observer.next({
                        completed: {
                            id: job.id,
                            subject: job.data.subject,
                            from: job.data.from,
                            to: job.data.to,
                            qty: job.progress,
                            completed: result,
                        },
                    })
                }
            })
        })

        return obs$.pipe(
            map((obs$) => ({
                data: {
                    active: obs$.active,
                    progress: obs$.progress,
                    completed: obs$.completed,
                },
            })),
        )
    }
}
```

Error:

```
(node:50677) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 completed listeners added to [Queue]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Comment: You subscribe bunch of events but never unsubscribe. It won't get automatically memory cleaned. You need to unsubscribe when progress is finished.